# Knockout computed observable not working

Tags: javascript, web-applications, knockout.js

I am using a Knockout computed observable to multiply two other observables. Unfortunately, the computed observable does not seem to be outputting any value.

```
var boyle1 = {
volume1_text: ko.observable(parseInt(2)),
volume1_select: ko.observable(parseInt(2))
};
boyle1.volume = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.volume1_text() * this.volume1_select();
}, boyle1);
ko.applyBindings(boyle1);
```

Both other observables work perfectly, and are easily binded to elements on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is any chance that you can put this and html code on jsFiddle?

Comment: @Austin It has something to do with your html binding to the computed. Please post your relevant html code. Here is a working example of your model and problem -- http://jsfiddle.net/YBr2m/1/

Comment: @FeistyMango You should put your comment as answer. With that solution he can find that he have typo or something that in his html code.

Comment: @FeistyMango Thanks. In doing that I found the typo I had. Sorry that I kind of wasted your time on that. If you put your comment as an answer, I will check it as correct. I think that gets you points or something (I am new to StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with your html binding to the computed. 
As you indicated it was in fact, a typo in the markup.

**Markup**

```
<input data-bind="value: volume1_text" />
<input data-bind="value: volume1_select" />
<br /><br />    
<span data-bind="text: volume"></span>
```

**Model**

```
var boyle1 = {
   volume1_text: ko.observable(parseInt(2)),
   volume1_select: ko.observable(parseInt(2))
};

boyle1.volume = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.volume1_text() * this.volume1_select();
}, boyle1);

ko.applyBindings(boyle1);
```

Here is a working example of your model and problem

http://jsfiddle.net/YBr2m/1